# How to remove a keyboard shortcut for Anaconda

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, anaconda

I just installed an **Anaconda SciPy distribution** (https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) on **Windows 8.1**. Whenever I press the right alt + a button combination, Anaconda console shows up. Why on the Earth they would assign such shortcut which is responsible for the **ą** char (Polish programmers keyboard). Do you know a solution for removing this keyboard shortcut without uninstalling Anaconda ? Maybe it is a background process which listens for this key press. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you go to the start screen and find the menu item for 'Anaconda Command Prompt'; right click on it and view properties -- is there a hotkey there?  You should be able to delete it.

I'll look into the installer to see if the new console shortcut was added with a hotkey binding -- I suspect it might have been.

Comment: You are right, there was a shortcut-key assigned. Removing an entry from properties solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first answer needs a little tweak.

Following the recipe as above:

1. Go to Metro Start Screen
2. Find Anaconda
3. Right click

... and then there is no option to change properties,

4. So click "Add to TaskBar"
5. when you see it on the TaskBar (Desktop Mode) then Right-Click and change properties.